# Delphi overwrite file and wrong modified date time

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, last-modified, filetime

I'd like to get a file **last modified** time in Delphi.

Normally something like `FileAge()` would do the trick, only the problem is: if I **overwrite** **File A** with **File B** using `CopyFile`, File A's **modified date is not updated with current overwrite time** as it should(?)

I get that: `CopyFile` also copy file attributes, but I really need to get the modified date that *also* works when a file is overwritten.

**Is there such function?** My whole application relies on modification time to decide whether or not I should proceed with files!

---

**EDIT** Just to clarify: I'm only monitoring the files. It's not my application who's modifying them.

Comment: don't use CopyFile,delete file A and create file B again.

Comment: I would use Windows Shell way with using of `SHFileOperation`.

Comment: I can't, I'm only monitoring the files. It's not me who's modifying them, but I still need to track changes :(

Comment: What does the create time returns for overwritten files?

Comment: Your question edit is then against the initial question. So you're just monitoring files and once you detect file change, you want to change the file's modified date ?

Comment: @TheVedge: I tried that: creation date is only good when *creating* a file, not overwriting it

Comment: @TLama: No, I want to `get` the modified file's date, not change it

Comment: Now I see. You're trying to monitor changes based on the modified date/time value and some foreign app uses `CopyFile` which doesn't update this value. This way is not safe if you're going to monitor changes by that. Imagine, that I can modify just this date/time in my file manager without actually changing the file content. In that case your application might be mislead by that.

Comment: @TLama: Exactly yes. I explained the [reason why I chose this approach here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487764/delphi-overwrite-file-and-wrong-modified-date-time#comment20189042_14487982), I'm hoping to be able to have both the ability to catch large changes *and* reliably get the modification time at the same time.

Comment: @TheVedge `CreateTime` get's totally wrong in this case -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172190/en-us (btw still the same with W7)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) says:

> File attributes for the existing file are copied to the new file.

Which means that you cannot use base your program on the last modified attribute of the file, or indeed any attribute of the file. Indeed there are all sorts of ways for the last modified attribute of the file to change. It can in fact go backwards in time.

Instead I suggest that you use [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) to keep track of modifications. That will allow you to receive notifications whenever a file is modified. You can write your program in an event based manner based on the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` API.

If you can't use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and the file attributes, then you'll have to base your decisions on the contents of the file.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that and I specifically mentioned it in my question. I also *do* use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (nice catch), but this doesn't `scale`: if a user is copying (or overwriting) a large folder (1000s files), the only way to catch all changes is to `scan` the folder itself instead of dealing with files one by one. That's why I was/am relying on the file modification to catch changes in the event of a large change.

Comment: Overwriting a folder containing 1000 files is not an extreme/unusual case. I have to handle this!

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that `ReadDirectoryChangesW` does not scale. If you would rather carry on using the last modified attribute, as you seem to indicate in that comment, then I don't really see the point of the question.

Comment: According to my tests `ReadDirectoryChangesW` will not catch every change *if* a user is overwriting a large folder containing 1000s files, that's what I meant by scaling.

Comment: Of course no I don't want to keep using the last modified attribute since clearly it's not reliable at all, but I *do* want to rely on something that can track (relatively) large changes, thus my question.

Comment: @TheDude If you have problems with `ReadDirectoryChanges` then you should ask about that (and post some code too)

Comment: @SirRufo: I don't have issues with `ReadDirectoryChanges`, I actually use it just fine, I just said that using it to track individual files doesn't scale. That's why I relied on file modification date attribute, which lead me to the issue that I discovered, thus my question if there's a reliable way to get file modified time

Comment: @TheDude I think ReadDirectoryChanges is flaky for network volumes when connections may be lost. But I don't see why it can't work reliably for large volumes of files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Regarding `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, if there are too many changes in a short period of time (which inevitably happen if you overwrite a folder containing a lot of files, for instance), I start getting ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR  (which means: `A notify change request is being completed and the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer. The caller now needs to enumerate the files to find the changes`). In my experience, too many change notifications not dealt with fast enough leads to this.

Comment: As I said, using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to track folder changes and scanning the modified folders is immune to the problem above, but now I see that I can't rely on file modification attribute either, which brings me back to square one :(

Comment: I'm still reading [this article](http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html) (which also link to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4465cafb-f4ed-434f-89d8-c85ced6ffaa8/)) that mention [Change Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx), I'm still reading this, but for anyone being in the same situation (ie. `ReadDirectoryChangesW` lost notifications), this may help

Comment: OK, I posted a question about [change journal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496630/implement-change-journal-in-delphi) (which probably is the way to go to avoid the file modif. mess), if anyone can help, please share the wisdom!